# How do I populate my html dropdown menu with data from the database?

Tags: php, html

I have a database called class_database. I have connection to my database through my php file. I believe my query is correct, however it will not populate into html dropdown menu. Listed below are the two sections of php I have written with the html dropdown menu included.

```
<?php
$mysqli= NEW MySQLi ('localhost' , 'root' , '' , 'class_database');
$resultSet = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM 'class_list' ORDER BY 'ClassNumber' DESC ");
?>
```

```
<select name="class_list">
<?php
while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
  $classnumbers = $rows['classnumbers'];
  echo "<option value='classnumbers'>$classnumbers</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

The above code results in a blank dropdown menu. How do I properly populate the dropdown menu?

Comment: _Side note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based admin tool for managing MySQL/MariaDB databases. Your application talks directly to the database and doesn't have anything to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: If it's blank, then the loop was never entered. Are you sure your query should return data?

Comment: `ORDER BY 'ClassNumber'` should either be `ORDER BY ClassNumber` or `ORDER BY \`ClassNumber\`` (back ticks, not single quotes). Same issue with `FROM 'class_list'`. However, you don't need to put the column names in back ticks unless they are reserved words in MySQL.

Comment: Aside from that, what is the point of creating *n* options with the same value? I believe you wanted to insert the variable there as well.

Comment: If some code which includes a database query doesn't work, I would recommend that you always start by testing the query in PHPMyAdmin (since you're using that) to see if it is correct or not, even if you believe it is.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I believe the back ticks helped. Now the dropdown menu actually drops down longer than it did. I have a new error stating that I have undefined indexes. This would be on the $classnumbers = $rows ['classnumbers'] line

Comment: Start by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined).

Comment: You don't actually need the back ticks at all in the above query. Neither `class_list` or `ClassNumber` are reserved words in MySQL.

Comment: oh okay I misread. It also worked without because as you said they aren't reserved words.

Comment: Technically the question was answered. The menu is now populated but not displaying the data properly. On to more troubleshooting! Thanks for the help you guys